# I want to sort, then delete in a range in multiple workbooks

Tags: excel, vba, with-statement

I have a range that uses Vlookups to reference a pivot table. my VBA code successfully updates the pivot tables, then sorts the range, so that the "#N/A" values are last.

To be as descriptive as I can: the entire table has 2 parts, based on 2 categories. Column B has all the references for the Vlookups (1,2,3, etc.) then Columns C:E populate. Then the first category (b2:e189) gets sorted so error values are last. then the second category (b191:e8040). Currently, I have to go through and manually delete (shift cells up, as I only want Columns A:E deleted) the error rows.

There are multiple workbooks (wb2, wb3, wb4) that this will apply to. So any part of the code shown below is replicated multiple times (with the wb# changing).

My VBA code works so far for sorting the categories by I cannot figure out how to then automatically delete (and shift cells up) the error values. Can it be done within the "with...end with" statement?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

'name and set this workbook

Dim wb1 As Excel.Workbook
    Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook

'name and set variables to all provider workbooks

Dim wb2 As Excel.Workbook: Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("H:\RVU Monthly Reports\2019 RVU Reports\Alonso_2019.xlsx")
Dim wb3 As Excel.Workbook: Set wb3 = Workbooks.Open("H:\RVU Monthly Reports\2019 RVU Reports\Apostolova_2019.xlsx")

'optimize macro speed
     Application.ScreenUpdating = False
     Application.EnableEvents = False
     Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Copying InvoiceDetail from Template to Provider Report
     wb1.Worksheets("InvoiceDetail").Range("A:BZ").Copy

'paste special_values to all workbooks
    wb2.Worksheets("InvoiceDetail").Range("A:BZ").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    wb3.Worksheets("InvoiceDetail").Range("A:BZ").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

'Refresh Pivot Tables

 Dim pc As PivotCache

'Refresh all pivot tables

'  For Each pc In wb1.PivotCaches
'     pc.Refresh
'     Next pc
For Each Workbook In Application.Workbooks: Workbook.RefreshAll: Next Workbook


'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Application.EnableEvents = True
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

'sort for worksheets


With wb2.Worksheets("Mar").Sort
    .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("c3"), Order:=xlAscending
    .SetRange Range("b2:e189")
    .Header = xlYes
    .Apply
    .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("c3"), Order:=xlAscending
    .SetRange Range("b191:e8040")
    .Header = xlYes
    .Apply
End With

With wb3.Worksheets("Mar").Sort
    .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("c3"), Order:=xlAscending
    .SetRange Range("b2:e189")
    .Header = xlYes
    .Apply
    .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("c3"), Order:=xlAscending
    .SetRange Range("b191:e8040")
    .Header = xlYes
    .Apply
End With


End Sub
```

Actual results: all books open, the reference sheet is copy/pasted, pivots are updated, and the necessary tables are sorted. Now I need to delete the "#N/A's"

Answer (score 0):

you can create a sub like that

```
Public Sub DeleteRowsWithError(st As Worksheet)
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In st.UsedRange
        c.Select
        If VBA.IsError(c) Then
            c.EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

And in the end of your code you can add this sub

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

'name and set this workbook

Dim wb1 As Excel.Workbook
    Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook

'name and set variables to all provider workbooks

Dim wb2 As Excel.Workbook: Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("H:\RVU Monthly Reports\2019 RVU Reports\Alonso_2019.xlsx")
Dim wb3 As Excel.Workbook: Set wb3 = Workbooks.Open("H:\RVU Monthly Reports\2019 RVU Reports\Apostolova_2019.xlsx")

'optimize macro speed
     Application.ScreenUpdating = False
     Application.EnableEvents = False
     Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Copying InvoiceDetail from Template to Provider Report
     wb1.Worksheets("InvoiceDetail").Range("A:BZ").Copy

'paste special_values to all workbooks
    wb2.Worksheets("InvoiceDetail").Range("A:BZ").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    wb3.Worksheets("InvoiceDetail").Range("A:BZ").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

'Refresh Pivot Tables

 Dim pc As PivotCache

'Refresh all pivot tables

'  For Each pc In wb1.PivotCaches
'     pc.Refresh
'     Next pc
For Each Workbook In Application.Workbooks: Workbook.RefreshAll: Next Workbook


'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Application.EnableEvents = True
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

'sort for worksheets


With wb2.Worksheets("Mar").Sort
    .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("c3"), Order:=xlAscending
    .SetRange Range("b2:e189")
    .Header = xlYes
    .Apply
    .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("c3"), Order:=xlAscending
    .SetRange Range("b191:e8040")
    .Header = xlYes
    .Apply
End With

With wb3.Worksheets("Mar").Sort
    .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("c3"), Order:=xlAscending
    .SetRange Range("b2:e189")
    .Header = xlYes
    .Apply
    .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("c3"), Order:=xlAscending
    .SetRange Range("b191:e8040")
    .Header = xlYes
    .Apply
End With

call DeleteRowsWithError(wb2)
call    DeleteRowsWithError (wb3)
End Sub
```